# Custom assertThatThrownBy

Tags: assertj

after reading this [article](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-custom-assertions.html) I was sure to write my own Assertions but I failed. :-(

We have an interface which looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationException extends RuntimeException {
    public String enhancedStatus() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

I wrote my own EnhancedStatusAssert like described in the artile.

```
public class EnhancedStatusAssert extends AbstractAssert<EnhancedStatusAssert, ApplicationException> {

    public EnhancedStatusAssert(ApplicationException actual) {
        super(actual, EnhancedStatusAssert.class);
    }

public static EnhancedStatusAssert assertThat(ApplicationException actual) {
    return new EnhancedStatusAssert(actual);
}

    public EnhancedStatusAssert hasEnhancedCause(String enhancedStatus) {
        isNotNull();

        // check condition
        if (!actual.enhancedStatus().equals(enhancedStatus)) {
            failWithMessage("Expected enhanced status to be <%s> but was <%s>", enhancedStatus, actual.enhancedStatus());
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Which works fine but then I have trouble to override assertThatThrownBy

```
assertThatThrownBy(() -> { throw new ApplicationException()})
    .isInstanceOf(ApplicationException.class)
    .hasEnhancedCause("cause");
```

What is the way to get it to run?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `asInstanceOf` https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-3.13.0-asInstanceOf you can write your own `InstanceOfAssertFactory` for your `ApplicationException`.

If you only have one field to check you can extract it with ... [extracting](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.14.0/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#extracting(java.util.function.Function)) and chain assertions on the extracted value.